# Backbone.Deferred.Collection triggers multiple 'add' event - How to handle these events in batch?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Here is my code:

```
class ActivityView extends App

  onInitialize: ->
    @activities = new Activities
    @activities.on 'add remove', @_renderActivityItems, @
```

When I retrieve data from my server endpoint, the response may contain a dozen data points. But whenever each piece of data is added to the collection, an 'add' event is triggered and the function `_renderActivityItems` is called numerous time.

It seems to be very costly because the function actually renders all the elements inside the collection.

Preferably the `_renderActivityItems` function should be called once after all the elements are added to the collection.

How can I achieve it with backbone event?

Comment: Are you using the Collection.fetch() method to initialise the collection? If so, add an the option {silent: true} to prevent the listener from triggering for fetch.

Comment: Great suggestion! How did you find out this option. I took a look at doc http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch  and it did not mention `silent`. BTW please convert your comment to answer so I can upvote.

Comment: It's in the docs, but hidden at the bottom of the events section. I found out about this after struggling with the same issue a few months ago :)

Comment: @AnthonyKong If the answer solved your problem, please accept it to indicate that the question is solved.

Comment: Not yet. Still need to test it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `Collection.fetch()` method to initialize the collection, add the option `{silent: true}` to prevent the listener from triggering for fetch.

Answer (score 2):

In Backbone 1.2.0  has been added the update event

> Added an "update" event that triggers after any amount of models are
>   added or removed from a collection. Handy to re-render lists of things
>   without debouncing.
>
> "update" (collection, options) — single event triggered after any
>   number of models have been added or removed from a collection.